# Joining two pandas dataframe by selecting apropriate rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, datatables

I have this two dataframes:

One with 65 rows. The column 'school' is the School's Id and they run from 1 to 65 and are unique.

[image: First dataframe]

The second dataframe reads:

[image: Second Dataframe]

And it has 12177 rows. The 'school' column runs from 1 to 65 and they are the same Ids from the first table. The column 'Student' are relative to student's Id and they are unique but they repeat as the column 'variable' changes (first they are 'intake', and then 'vr' and then 'standLRT' etc).

What I want is to merge these two tables into only one such that the student Id will represent the rows, and the columns will be its school's Id, its grades, vr, intake score etc etc etc. I do not know how to proceed. How can I select a student Id, say 145, from school 1 with intake and value mid 50% etc and make it a row where 'school = 1 ' is a column?

That is, a want this table:

| Student | School | Intake | Vr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 143 | 1 | mid50% | 3 |
| another | 3 | somethng | xx |

How can I proceed? Some tips?

Comment: does `df.pivot(columns='variable', index=['student', 'school'])` work (2nd dataframe)?

Comment: No, because there are duplicate entries in 'school' and 'student'. It is a large dataset so I cannot show it here, but the 'student' column contains student 143, 145, 149..... for school 1 and variable value 'intake', then it repeats school 1 and students all over again for variable sex etc